# What is an QWebKit analog

Tags: c++, qt, web, browser, webkit

After i spent couple days to figure out how use QWebKit library in my QT application for my  browser, i found that it [removed year ago](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76739/webkit-status-2017).

And no info what i can use instead, and also no information WHY such good feature was removed, it was easy to create  web page just writing couple lines of code.

P.S. i'm already downloaded all kits but it didn"t help:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QWebKit` API was designed for synchronous function calls, which runs on the main thread and on loading heavy web pages can block your GUI.

The alternative is the [QWebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html).

Qt WebEngine uses a multi-process architecture, he's designed for asynchronous function calls. And also based on chromium.

To Port to web-engine [read this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)

Comment: Thanks! Now it's become clear for me. But cant run simpliest examples from Qt official documentations or other tutorials, have 3 errors like that: "main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QWebEngineView::QWebEngineView(class QWidget *)" (__imp_??0QWebEngineView@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function main"

Maybe its because my include looks like this:
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView>

Anyway, there is no possibility include QWebEngineView directly

Comment: add to the makefile 'QT += webenginewidgets'

Comment: God bless you!!

Answer (score 0):

QtWebEngine is a chromium based alternative which is supported on Desktop platforms, see [webengine-in-qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-web-content.html#webengine-in-qt). It also provides the `Qt WebView` module, which uses the native web engine of the platform and is available for Android/iOS as well.